# How can i get the position or index using template XSLT

Tags: http, xslt

XML:

```
  <Grandparent>
         <Parent>
                 <Children>
                       <Info>
                           <Name>
                              <label id="chname"/>
                           </Name>
                       </Info>
                 </Children>

                 <Children>
                       <Info>
                           <Name>
                              <label id="chname"/>
                           </Name>
                       </Info>
                 </Children
                <Children>
                       <Info>
                           <Name>
                              <label id="chname"/>
                           </Name>
                       </Info>
                 </Children

         </Parent>
    </Grandparent>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match"/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="GrandParent/Parent/Children" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Children">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Children/Info/Name/label">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="childCtr" select="Parent/Children[position()]"/>

        <xsl:attribute name="text">
                     <xsl:value-of select="$childCtr"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />

     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <!--Identity template copies content forward -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

how can i get the index or position of "children" using template while adding attribute to a label tag and getting the whole "children" node?

like:

```
 Parent[0] = Children1,
 Parent[1] = Children2,
 Parent[2] = Children3
```

how can i get this kind of thing? I need some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: XML contains errors: GrandParant (must be with capitol P), and Children end tags aren't correct.

Comment: Please show your expect XML output. Please also fix up the errors in your sample input document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a listing of your expected output, it is hard to tell what you want, but maybe this is it...

**This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="label">
  <label text="{count(../../../preceding-sibling::Children) + 1}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </label>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied to this input...**

```
<Grandparent>
    <Parent>
        <Children>
            <Info>
                <Name>
                    <label id="chname"/>
                </Name>
            </Info>
        </Children>
        <Children>
            <Info>
                <Name>
                    <label id="chname"/>
                </Name>
            </Info>
        </Children>
        <Children>
            <Info>
                <Name>
                    <label id="chname"/>
                </Name>
            </Info>
        </Children>
    </Parent>
</Grandparent>
```

**...will yield...**

```
<Grandparent>
  <Parent>
    <Children>
      <Info>
        <Name>
          <label text="1" id="chname" />
        </Name>
      </Info>
    </Children>
    <Children>
      <Info>
        <Name>
          <label text="2" id="chname" />
        </Name>
      </Info>
    </Children>
    <Children>
      <Info>
        <Name>
          <label text="3" id="chname" />
        </Name>
      </Info>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
</Grandparent>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. It works, now i understand how the "preceding-sibling:Parent" works. I just miss this one "../" (step higher) :)

Answer (score 1):

Tunneling (XSLT 2.0 feature) a parameter set by the children template:

```
<xsl:template match="Children">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="childPosition" select="position()" tunnel="yes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Children/Info/Name/label">
    <xsl:param name="childPosition" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="$childPosition"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: what version of xsl does have tunneling feature? It shows a syntax error

Comment: @iCeR- tunneling feature is in xslt 2.0

Comment: @Joepie Is there any way  to pass param in this scenario without using tunneling? Sadly my xslt does not support tunneling. :(

Comment: Tunneling is indeed a XSLT 2.0 feature. You could add the parameter to all templates, but this gets messy fast. Use one of the other answers for the XSLT 1.0 solution: count(ancestor::Children/preceding-sibling::Children)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="childCtr" select="count(ancestor::Children/preceding-sibling::Children)"/>
```